# c# singleline textbox autocomplete на Tab key

Tags: c#, winforms

Для завершения autocomplet'a используется клавиша <kbd>Tab</kbd>, как и для перебора `TextBox`'ов. Как убрать перебор при autocomplet'е, чтобы <kbd>Tab</kbd> завершал ввод, но не переводил на следующий текстбокс?

Upd: Чтобы внести ясность: есть солюшн в Visual studio, который нужно поправить. Описание проблемы выше.

Comment: Asp.Net? WinForms? или может быть XAML? что используется то?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Используется WinForms

Comment: Автодополнение также завершается при нажатии `Enter`. Может не стоит и заморачиваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выставить всем `TextBox`ам `TabStop=false` или фильтровать нажатия клавиш.